# Mixing registerScript (with PHP variables) with registerPackage in Yii

Tags: javascript, php, yii

I'm developing a Web Application using Yii Framework. I started by hardcoding javascript and css files (even though it might not be the best pratice, I use this method in another application).

I'm trying to achieve something like this:

```
<html><head>
....
(css includes)
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.myapp.com/js/vendor/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($) {
    if (typeof(myapp) == "undefined") { var myapp = {}; }

    var myapp = {
        ui : {},
        var: {}
    };
    myapp.var = {
        baseurl: '<?php Yii::app()->getBaseUrl()'
    };
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.myapp.com/js/myapp.dialog.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.myapp.com/js/myapp.customjqgrid.js"></script>
```

So, I created two packages in config/main.php:
package 'jquery' that includes jquery (first script)
package 'commonjs' that includes my common files (myapp.dialog.js and myapp.customjqgrid.js)

However, both myapp.dialog.js and myapp.customjagrid.js use the variable "myapp.var.baseurl". So, the order of the includes must be:

```
package jquery
inline jquery
package commonjs.
```

My PHP in layout is something like this:

```
<?php 
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerPackage('jquery');
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('helpers', "
    if (typeof(myapp) == 'undefined') { var myapp = {}; }
    var myapp = {
        ui : {},
        var: {}
    };
    myapp.var = {
        baseurl = '".Yii::app()->getBaseUrl()."/'
    };
", CClientScript::POS_READY);
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerPackage('commonjs');
?>
```

The problem is that I can't define a position of registerScript relative to registerPackage or define a dependency between registerScript and registerPackage.
I know it is possible to define dependencies between packages, but then how could I pass my PHP variables to JS ?

Is there an easy way to do this or is it better to continue to include JS and CSS manually?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, packages are not suited for such usage.

You either work as it is: register package then register base url script

or

create widget, with sole purpose to include your scripts and generate JS variables in one single file. That way you would replace your "registerPackage" with "widget" method and you will get same result.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I kept the code as it was. I will wait for Yii2 GA, which might resolve the issue.